# Java kernel32.ReadFile error (ByteBuffer cannot be converted to byte[])

Tags: java

I am trying to read a NamedPipe in Java with the following code:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4*1024);
IntByReference bytesRead = new IntByReference(buffer.capacity()); 
int lastError = 0;
if (kernel32.PeekNamedPipe(pipeHandle, buffer, buffer.capacity(), bytesRead, null, null))
        while ( !(kernel32.ReadFile(pipeHandle, /*(!)ERROR HERE==>*/buffer, buffer.capacity(), bytesRead, overlapped)) || (lastError=kernel32.GetLastError()) == Kernel32.ERROR_MORE_DATA){
                if (lastError == Kernel32.ERROR_PIPE_NOT_CONNECTED || overlapped.Internal.intValue() != WinNT.ERROR_IO_PENDING)
                        break;
                }
```

But it fails with the following error: `incompatible types: ByteBuffer cannot be converted to byte[]`. I tried to replace `buffer` with `b` from `byte[] b = new byte[buffer.remaining()];` but the program started to work wrong. Any ideas how the error may be fixed would be welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved with this:

```
byte[] b = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
```

Examined again the return of the program.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use buffer.array() instead of buffer in kernel32.ReadFile(...) call as second parameter. So it will look as

```
kernel32.ReadFile(pipeHandle, buffer.array(), ...)
```